# When uncheck Modify Security Settings in MySQL Installtaion, Access Denied root@localhost

Tags: mysql, passwords, installation, root

I'm installing MySql 5.1 on Windows using Installer.

On the security options step, I didn't check Modify Security Settings and go next
[image]

And I got Access Denied message when want to log in as root

Access Denied for user root@ localhost (using password:No)

What's wrong and why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have never set a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root. But its not clear how you tried to login as root.

Anyway you can RESET the root password by following [these steps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html#idp152165392).